# Issue about green text

Tags: web-services

I am using Green Text Account and using  http://developer.textapp.net/WebService  api call for sending sms. In that we are taking mobile number from user and sending sms.

I am having query, if user in UK  doesn’t enter the country code(+44)  whether he can get the message if he enters mobile number in the format     with leading zero and the server is in UK only.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for the [Destinations parameter](http://developer.textapp.net/WebService/Parameters_Destinations.aspx) used in the [SendSMS method](http://developer.textapp.net/WebService/Methods_SendSMS.aspx) says:

> Phone numbers **must be formatted in their full international format,
>   beginning with a +,** followed by the appropriate country code, **with
>   the removal of any leading zeros**, and with no extraneous characters
>   or spaces. Numbers can include both mobile and landline numbers.
>
> For example, mobile number (07836) 123-456 would be formatted as
>   +447836123456.
>
> An example of a string containing multiple numbers:
>
> +336456232125,+617766789712,+447836123456